# SVT-AV1: After encoding the video seeking is very bad in any video player (even HTML5)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-encoding

i am using SVT-AV1 and FFMPEG to encode Videos into the AV1 video and opus audio codec (.webm), it works fine, except that the video seeking do not work really (extremly bad). When i seek, the CPU useage jumps up and it takes up to minutes until the seeking process finishes.

Here is how i encode the videos:

1. Convert any video into yuv: `ffmpeg -i <src-video> -preset veryslow -level 6.2 <out-video>.yuv`
2. First AV1 run `svt-av1 -i '<out-video>.yuv' -w <src-video-width> -h <src-video-height> --fps <src-video-fps> --rc 0 -q 30 --preset 8 -b '.\output1.ivf' --output-stat-file '.\stat_file.stat' --keyint 1 --enable-restoration-filtering 1`
3. Second AV1 run `svt-av1 -i '<out-video>.yuv' -w <src-video-width> -h <src-video-height> --fps <src-video-fps> --rc 0 -q 30 --preset 3 -b '.\output.ivf' --input-stat-file '.\stat_file.stat' --keyint 1 --enable-restoration-filtering 1`
4. Get source video audio in opus codec `ffmpeg -i <src-video> -c:a libopus -vn -preset veryslow -level 6.2 output.ogg`
5. Get final .webm video `ffmpeg -i output.ivf -i output.ogg -c copy output.webm`

I have allready tryed to play with the --keyin option, also just letting it away and use the encoder default, but the results are always the same. (`--keyin 1` seems to work better than without this option, but also very very bad)

What am i doing wrong?

Extras: I am using Windows 10 with downloaded version of SVT-AV1 and FFMPEG (I just renamed the SVT-AV1 Encoder .exe file to be `svt-av1.exe`). Used CPU is Ryzen 9 3900X

Answer (score 1):

Use `--irefresh-type 2` in SVT-AV1.

It needs to use IDR mode (the default mode is CRA).

For more information:

- https://github.com/OpenVisualCloud/SVT-AV1/issues/170
- https://github.com/OpenVisualCloud/SVT-AV1/issues/33#issuecomment-472354659

Comment: Ty very much, this helped.